# How to retrieve images dynamically from server in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
<img class="img-responsive" :src="'http://10.20.10.161:8000/content_images/'+video.image" >
```

In place of `http://10.20.10.161:8000` I need some predefined variable as base url of my server application.

How can I set that?

Answer (score 0):

`<img class="img-responsive" :src="getContentImageLink(video.image)" >`

In Vue DOM we will call a function.

`getContentImageLink(video_image) {
   return this.$http.options.root + '/content_images/' + video_image;
}`

Then in scription we will return full link of image with predefined base url which has to be set in `main.js` file.

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://10.20.10.161:8000'
```

good option I got to do this.
If anyone get better option, please comment.